# mysql calculation answer into empty column

Tags: mysql

I want to put the difference (Diff) between the price every minute into an empty column in a table in mysql using sql code. I E the price change every minute.
Before:

```
Date,    Time,   Price,  Diff  
20140101,230300, 1.3761, NULL
20140101,230400, 1.3762, NULL
```

After sql code has been run:

```
Date,    Time,   Price,  Diff  
20140101,230300, 1.3761, 0.0000
20140101,230400, 1.3762, 0.0001
```

Comment: Consider providing datetime as a single entity. And I doubt that this data set is adequately representative of the problem.

Comment: This is likely going to be some sort of join, marrying each row to the one from a minute earlier, then calculating the difference. Made hard by not using datetime columns for datetime values.

Comment: How do I make the Date and Time to one entity?

Comment: declare a column to contain a [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) value

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no real reason to put the difference in the table. You can get the difference in a simple self join query

Approximately:

```
select ta.date, ta.time, ta.price, diff as ta.price-tb.price
from mytable ta join mytable tb 
where tb.time = ta.time-100;
```

The comment regarding having the datetime as a single entity will make the time difference calculation for the table much easier as there are functions such as TIMEDIFF to help.

Comment: I always put an outline answer and then pad it out with more info as I have in this case... :-)

Comment: Removed my comment as now it looks valid. Your first answer attracted -1 from someone ... this edited one will attract +1 from me.

Comment: Also, you have a small mistake there `mytable ta ta`

Comment: @Rahul I put the -1 on it when the answer was just a vague description of an idea, and not a proof of concept. Now he's fleshed it out with a sample I'll remove it.

Comment: I have merged the Date and the Time. But I still get an error on the dot at the ta.price after as. select ta.DateTime, ta.Price, Diff as ta.Price-tb.Price
from 'table 2' ta join 'table 2' tb 
where tb.DateTime = tb.DateTime-100;

Comment: @user3737287 If you have a single datetime column use `ta.DateTime = DATE_SUB(tb.DateTime, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);`

Comment: I still get an error at row 1. At the dot. Error code 1064.I have mysql version 5.6.16.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. DateTime is a reserved word, it doesn't like you using it. Either rename the column or wrap it in backticks: `ta.\`DateTime\` = DATE_SUB(tb.\`DateTime\`, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE);`